# Using of new date() in php script and dygraphs

Tags: php, mysql, date, dygraphs

I'm trying to retreive data from a mysql then transfert my data to dygraphs

So what working directly in javascript

```
 new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
          [

[ new Date("2009/07/12"), 100, 200 ],
[ new Date("2009/07/19"), 150, 220 ]
          ],
          {
            labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ]
          });
```

And what is not working with usage of php to retreive value from data base :

```
new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
          [ 

            <?php
            mysql_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "MyUser", "MyPassword") or
            die("Impossible de se connecter : " . mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("esync");


            $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, _date, ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.Val
            FROM ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY
            INNER JOIN ESYNC_TAGS ON ESYNC_TAGSHISTORY.TAGID=ESYNC_TAGS.ID
            WHERE ESYNC_TAGS.NAME='I_TT_21052'  AND ESYNC_TAGS.STATIONID=1 AND (_date BETWEEN now()-INTERVAL 45 MINUTE AND now());");

            $return_arr = array();

            //while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $numResults = mysql_num_rows($result);  

            $counter = 0;           

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $date = date_create($row['_date']);
                $date = $date->format('d/m/y H:i:s');   //format the date
                $b=$row['Val'];


            echo "[".$date.",".$b."],";


            };

            ?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: one suggestion that immediately screams at me, is don't use `mysql` lib in php, use `mysqli` or `pdo` because you're prone for SQL injection attacks here...

Comment: Also, you don't do anything with return_arr

Comment: I will take that in consideration, but still my first projet with mysql, so please be indulgent !

Comment: thats ok man, we've all been there :)

Comment: So change as been made to reflect mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i've loaded my data with CSV format as

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


                $a= date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($row['_date']));  //converting into required format of date



                $b=$row['Val'];

                if (++$counter == $numResults) {
                echo  '"'.$a.",".$b.'"'." ,";
                } else {
                echo  '"'.$a.",".$b.'\n"'." +". "\n";
                }



            };
```